# View attendees of a meeting which I already accepted in Outlook 2016

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I see who is attending a meeting to which I have already accepted an invite to ?

I can see who the invite is sent to before accepting, but not after.

[image]

I can see the times etc and the organizer, but not the other people in attendance.

I have tried double clicking the event, cannot see any options or information on attendees.

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can just open the event and click the Scheduling Assistant button (in your second screenshot) to view other attendees:

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that this is the list of people who have been invited. Depending on the permissions and the complexity of their calendar, you might be able to infer attendance - but it's not as easy as if you are the meeting owner.

Comment: This doesn't show the persons who have accepted, just all of the invited ones.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon I only needed to see the people who were invited

Answer (score 8):

If you have Outlook Social Connector, you can see meeting attendees via the [People Pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-on-the-outlook-social-connector-255447e8-82cd-48e7-9b79-1dd8721a2907):

[image]

To open the People Pane, click on "View > People Pane", and then "Normal" inside the main Outlook window.

Comment: This also do not show who has accepted and who not.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon True, but I assume this is intended. People who want to share with others which meetings they will be attending can do so by sharing their calendar.

Comment: Great answer - I used to be able to go to the Scheduling Assistant but this seems to have disappeared recently (not sure if due to and update or policy change within organisation)

Answer (score 5):

You can also click "Respond" then "Reply To All".  Outlook will create an email populated with the participants.  You can then discard the draft.  (Office 365)

Answer (score 3):

Outlooks seems to have been updated recently, because there is now a "Tracking" tab. Open your meeting in a new window (double click) → go to Tracking tab:
[image]

Wish this would be accessible without having to open the meeting in a new window, but at least it works.

Comment: Tracking tab is available only for the Meeting Organizer

Comment: @IlyaSerbis - I'm looking at the Tracking tab right now for a meeting where someone else is the Meeting Organizer, and I'm not even required, but an "Optional Attendee". I'm using MS 365 Apps for enterprise. Maybe other versions of Outlook don't open up this feature to all attendees? What's your version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Outlook Office 365, you can just open the event, and click the Scheduling Assistant button in the menu as shown here
[New view for Scheduling Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuYV4.png)
In Office 365 the Scheduling Assistant is IN A different place, IT IS A MENU not a BUTTON. Just in case you do not find it here the photo.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however it is the same as the accepted answer already provided